# Unexpected response returned by WCF Service: (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I've implemented a small set of REST services using WCF. One of the services recieves a large amount of data. When calling it (this is when runnig it from visual studio - I haven't deployed itto a production server yet) I get the error

> The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.

My web config

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderDataService" 
         closeTimeout="00:10:00"
         openTimeout="00:10:00" 
         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
         sendTimeout="00:10:00"
         allowCookies="false" 
         bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
         hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         textEncoding="utf-8" 
         transferMode="Buffered" 
         useDefaultWebProxy="true"
         messageEncoding="Text">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" 
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
               proxyCredentialType="None" 
               realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
             algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

Comment: where are you hosting that? in IIS?

Comment: my data is only 20KB . when i convert object to JSON .

Comment: In your **service** config, do you define the same binding, and did you assign that binding to an explicit endpoint?  Can you post the `<system.serviceModel>` section of your service's config?

Comment: In my code i dynamically change End Point URL. Will they effect?

Comment: Pleae find the code below for changing endpoint dynamically 

`SalesOrderDataServiceClient _sodataservice = new SalesOrderDataServiceClient();
string[]  EndPointURLSplitups = _sodataservice.Endpoint.Address.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Split('/');
                _sodataservice.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(new Uri(enpointurl + "/" + EndPointURLSplitups[EndPointURLSplitups.Length - 1]),
      _sodataservice.Endpoint.Address.Identity, _sodataservice.Endpoint.Address.Headers);
                _salesOrderDataService = _sodataservice;`

Comment: Enable service tracing on server side. Post full stack trace.

Comment: @jstreet how to enable it?

Comment: [Configuring Tracing - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: And then inspect it using [Service Trace Viewer Tool - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Server stack trace: 
   at `System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)`

Comment: @Rakin - the code you posted for calling he service is code for making a SOAP call, not a REST call.  Please post the complete `<system.serviceModel>` section from your Web.config file, as well as the complete code you're using to call the service.  This is a **very** common issue and there are a number of reasons you can be encountering it, but without more information the answers provided will be a guessing game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to increasing message size and buffer size quotes, consider also increase **maxItemsInObjectGraph** for serializer. It can matter if your object has complex structure or array of objects inside.
Our typical setting look so

```
 <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GlobalEndpoint">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1365536" />
    </behavior>
 </behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="GlobalBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1365536" />
    </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
```

And additionaly what Zwan has proposed

Answer (score 4):

Seem you exceed quota augment those value.

```
 maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000" maxBufferSize="2000000">
```

(or review your query for a lower result when possible)

if nothing work check here its like comon probleme.

[The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26463809/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-413-request-entity-too-large)

Comment: earlier i used 2000000 .. changed to 2147483647 when i see some articles related to this

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid your client is fine but you need to check the server web.config

add value the same way you did for your client

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly your request is the one that is delivering large amounts of data. That means that you have to edit the maxRecievedMessageSize like @Zwan have written. Not in the client's config but in the rest services config to allow big requests of data.

Comment: I would have written it as a comment if I had the reputation, unfortunately I am not yet allowed to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the **"maxItemsInObjectGraph"** size in web.config file, as this change worked for me.For details please see.

Comment: For details please see.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.maxitemsinobjectgraph(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you host the wcf rest service in a asp.net application, the **httpRuntime** limits must also be set because wcf service is running in ASP .NET compatibilty mode. Note that **maxRequestLength** has value in kilobytes

```
<configuration> <system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" /> </system.web> </configuration>
```

Refer at [The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large](http://forums.asp.net/t/1942234.aspx?The%20remote%20server%20returned%20an%20error%20413%20Request%20Entity%20Too%20Large%20)

More advice should make Dispose, destructor for services

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647)]
[GlobalErrorBehaviorAttribute(typeof(GlobalErrorHandler))]
public partial class YourService : IYourService
{

    // Flag: Has Dispose already been called? 
    bool disposed = false;
    // Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
    SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);

    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers. 
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern. 
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            handle.Dispose();
            // Free any other managed objects here. 
            //
        }

        // Free any unmanaged objects here. 
        //
        disposed = true;
    }

    ~YourService()  // destructor
    {
      Dispose();
    }
```

}

Hope it helps!

Comment: <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200" maxRequestLength="1024000" appRequestQueueLimit="300"/>

Comment: Server settingd <httpRuntime  executionTimeout="200000" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />

Comment: More advice should make Dispose, destructor for service. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since ok with maxRecievedMessageSize, you can check "IIS Request Filtering"
where maximum length of content in a request, in bytes

Also in the IIS – “UploadReadAheadSize” that prevents upload and download of data greater than 49KB. The value present by default is 49152 bytes and can be increased up to 4 GB.